# Unable to rename title of window popup displaying PDF as blob [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs

*I am opening a PDF file as blob in a popup window. I want to rename the title of the window. But not able to do it. Currently its showing some UUID as a title of the window.*

Code snippet to open the file.

```
var blob = new window.Blob([$scope.pdfBlob], { type: 'application/pdf' });    
var reader = new window.FileReader();    
reader.onloadend = function () {    
         var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
         window.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500');    
};    
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

*I've even tried using below code, but still unable to rename window title.*

```
var w = window.open(url, 'test', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500');    
w.onload = function() { this.document.title = "your new title"; }
```